# Как изменить фон слова с content script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, chrome-extension

Нужно чтобы слово меняло цвет фона

**style.css**

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**content.js**

```
 walk(document.body);

    function walk(node)  
    {

    var child, next;

    switch ( node.nodeType )  
    {
        case 1: 
        case 9:  
        case 11: 
            child = node.firstChild;
            while ( child ) 
            {
                next = child.nextSibling; 
                walk(child);
                child = next;
            }
            break;

        case 3: 
            handleText(node);
            break;
    }
}

function handleText(textNode) 
{
    var v = textNode.nodeValue;

    v = v.replace(/Apple/gi, '<span class="red">Pineapple</span>');

    textNode.nodeValue = v;
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте менять не nodeValue, а innerHTML.

Comment: Не получится. Надо в другом месте делать.